# Silverlight - Creating a rectangle that grows/shrinks to accommodate the text of a label within it

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0

Pretty straight forward. I have a rectangle with a label over top of it. I'f like to know how to get the rectangle to scale to fit the text.

my XAML:

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Height="158" Width="264">
    <Rectangle Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="rectangle1" Stroke="Black" MinWidth="40"  StrokeThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"  RadiusX="6" RadiusY="6" Fill="#1b6487" Width="64"></Rectangle>
    <sdk:Label Margin="9,3,209,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Content="$999.99" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove your explicit widths and heights.

You've got the Rectangle and the Label in the same cell of the Grid, so by default they *will* be the same size. You're overriding that and telling them not to be.

Alternatively, you could wrap a Border around your Label. This is the sort of thing that Border is meant for.